# Why when I'm using protractor to write a text it doens't work correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I have a textarea and I'm trying to write a big text on it. 
I'm using:

```
var ementa = element(by.xpath("//label[. = 'Descrição / Ementa*']/following-sibling::textarea"));
        ementa.sendKeys('TESTANDO1-TESTANDO2-TESTANDO3-TESTANDO4-TESTANDO5-TESTANDO6-TESTANDO7-TESTANDO8');
```

But, when I run the test, the proctractor makes a mess and write something like "T1TRES2". Why? How can I Fix it?

Comment: which browser are you using? and are you using angular 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm using angular2 and using google chrome.

Comment: is there a difference in the way protractor works?

Comment: there is no difference, this issue was due to a fix in angular 2 's event emitter, due to which protractor was not able to send the text to the text fields properly now with the new version it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using Angular 2 , there were some issues with `sendKeys()` in Angular 2 but they are fixed with latest version- **Angular 2.0.0-rc.3**. for more info you can check out this issue - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3196

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
element(by.model('model of the text area')).sendKeys('your text');
```

Comment: I tried using by.id because I don't have a model. It didn't work too